# Retrieving date list from Oracle database

Tags: oracle

I have a table like this

```
Start_Date                       End_Date
----------------------------------------------------    
21-02-2016 11:04:41              23-02-2016 11:04:41
21-02-2016 14:03:29              25-02-2016 14:03:29
22-02-2016 14:03:29              25-02-2016 14:03:29
```

If input is `21-Feb-2016` then I want to fetch all the rows if the given input falls between the `Start_Date` and `End_Date`. In these case the output should be

Output (truncating the time part)

```
Start_Date                            End_Date
------------------------------------------------
21-02-2016                            23-02-2016
21-02-2016                            25-02-2016
```

I tried the below query but somehow it didn't return the required result:

```
Select Start_Date, End_Date 
from TEST 
where Start_Date <= 21-02-2016 and End_Date >= 23-02-2016
```

Can someone tell me where I have made mistake and provide a proper solution for it

Comment: What data type are `start_date` and `end_date`? Dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table fields are in date format, you need something like the following:

```
select *
from test
where to_date('21-02-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy') between trunc(start_date) and trunc(end_date)
```

Otherwise, if they are stored as strings ( and I hope not) you need:

```
select *
from test
where to_date('21-02-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy') between
        trunc( to_date(start_date,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ) and
        trunc( to_date(end_date,  'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') )
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should also use the trunc function to filter the dates

```
Select Start_Date,End_Date from TEST 
where to_date('21-02-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') between trunc(start_date) and trunc(end_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       TRUNC( start_date ) AS truncated_start_date,
       TRUNC( end_date )   AS truncated_end_date
FROM   your_table
WHERE  DATE '2016-02-21' BETWEEN TRUNC( start_date ) AND TRUNC( end_date )
```